# Calculation the number of white pieces on the masterMind game in C

Tags: c

Forgive me for any writing mistakes english is not my first languange.

I'm coding the MasterMind (if you are not familiar with the game you can consult its rules in here https://magisterrex.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/mastermindrules.pdf) game in C to take part in a larger project, i pretty much finish it but i'm stuck in the function when the program calculates the number of white pieces; a white piece is basically when the player guess's the right colour in the wrong spot.
My code for that function doesn't work if the board (generate at random by the computer) as two pieces of the same color and the player guesses one of them in the wrong place.
The code is in portuguese (my native tongue) i hope that doesn't prevent my from getting help.
Thanks for yout help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>


#define STRING_MAXIMO 10

void gerarTabuleiro(int nivel, char (*tabuleiro)[STRING_MAXIMO])
{
    //Declaração e inicialização de variaveis locais 
    //Arrays de onde serão escolhidas aleatoriamente as cores de acordo com o nivel escolhido
    char coresNivel1[6][STRING_MAXIMO] = {"vermelho", "verde", "azul", "amarelo", "rosa", "ciano"};
    char coresNivel2[7][STRING_MAXIMO] = {"vermelho", "verde", "azul", "amarelo", "rosa", "ciano", "castanho"};
    char coresNivel3[8][STRING_MAXIMO] = {"vermelho", "verde", "azul", "amarelo", "rosa", "ciano", "castanho", "roxo"};
    int index;//Variavel que controlar todos os ciclos desta função

    srand(time(NULL));//Iremos alimentar o tabueleiro com uma uma nova combinação de todas as vezes (rand irá se basear na data e hora do sistema)

    if(nivel == 1){//Nivel 1 selecionado
        for(index = 0; index != nivel + 3; index++)//Para cada posição do tabuleiro (4 peças)
            strcpy(tabuleiro[index], coresNivel1[rand() % 6]);//Será escolhido aleatoriamente uma cor do array pre-determinado
    }
    else if(nivel == 2){//Nivel 2 selecionado
        for(index = 0; index != nivel + 3; index++)//Para cada posição do tabuleiro (5 peças)
            strcpy(tabuleiro[index], coresNivel2[rand() % 7]);//Será escolhido aleatoriamente uma cor do array pre-determinado
    }
    else if(nivel == 3){//Nivel 3 selecionado
        for(index = 0; index != nivel + 3; index++)//Para cada posição do tabuleiro (6 peças)
            strcpy(tabuleiro[index], coresNivel3[rand() % 8]);//Será escolhido aleatoriamente uma cor do array pre-determinado
    }
}

int calculaPretas(int nivel, char (*tabuleiro)[STRING_MAXIMO], char (*palpite)[STRING_MAXIMO])
{
    //Declaração e incialização de variaveis locais 
    int index;//Variaveis que controlarão os ciclos para iterar sobre o tabuleiro e o palpite do jogador 
    int nDp = 0;//Variavel auxiliar que ira controlar o numero de acertos na posição correta do utilizador 

    for(index = 0; index != nivel + 3; index++){/*Iremos simultaneamente comparar o primeiro palpite do utilizador com a primeira posição do tabuleiro,
    o segundo palpite com a segunda posição e assim sucessivamente*/
        if(strcmp(palpite[index], tabuleiro[index]) == 0)//Caso a cor seja correta
            nDp++;//Iremos incrementar o numero de peças acertadas em uma unidade
    }
    return nDp;
}

int calculaBrancas(int nivel, char (*tabuleiro)[STRING_MAXIMO], char (*palpite)[STRING_MAXIMO])
{
    //Declaração e incialização de variaveis locais 
    int indexT, indexP;//Variaveis que controlarão os ciclos para iterar sobre o tabuleiro e o palpite do jogador (indexT iterara sobre o tabuleiro e indexP iterara sobre o palpite)
    int nDp = 0;//Variavel auxiliar que ira controlar o numero de acertos na posição errada do utilizador
    int contabilizado[nivel+3];//Vetor que irá armazenar se um elemento do palpite já foi contabilizado como peça branca

    //Inicialização do array a 0, pois uma posição será colocada a 1 sempre que essa peça branca já tenha sido contabilizada
    for(int index = 0; index != nivel + 3; index++)
        contabilizado[index] = 0;

    for(indexP = 0; indexP != nivel + 3; indexP++){//Ciclo que ira iterar sobre o palpite fornecido pelo jogador
        for(indexT = 0; indexT != nivel + 3; indexT++){//Ciclo que ira iterar sobre as peças do tabuleiro
            if((strcmp(palpite[indexP], tabuleiro[indexT]) == 0) && indexP != indexT && !contabilizado[indexP]){//Iremos verificar se a cor existe no tabuleiro mas esta colocada na posição errada
                nDp++;//Incremento do numero de peças brancas no tabuleiro
                contabilizado[indexP] = 1;//Incremento da peça contabilizada ao array          
            }
        }
    }
    return nDp;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    //Declaração e inicialização de variaveis locais (automaticas)
    int nivel;//Variavel que ira permitir ao utilizador selecionar o numero de peças no tabuleiro e as cores usadas
    int numeroDecasas;//Varivel que guardará o numero de casas de acordo com o nivel escolhido 
    int index;//Variavel que controlar todos os ciclos desta função

    //Explicação das regras do jogo 
    printf("#############################################################################################################\n");
    printf("# O objectivo do Mastermind é descobrir uma combinação de cores determinada aleatoriamente pelo computador. #\n");
    printf("# Para tal e necessario que escolha o nivel de jogo adequado                                                #\n");
    printf("# Nivel 1 -> 4 casas e 6 cores possiveis                                                                    #\n");
    printf("# Nivel 2 -> 5 casas e 7 cores possiveis                                                                    #\n");
    printf("# Nivel 3 -> 6 casas e 8 cores possiveis                                                                    #\n");
    printf("# Escolha o nivel pretendido                                                                                #\n");
    scanf("%i", &nivel); 
    printf("# Nivel %i selecionado                                                                                       #\n", nivel);
    printf("#############################################################################################################\n\n\n");

    //Declaração condicional do tamanho do tabuleiro de acordo com o nivel escolhido 
    char tabuleiro[nivel + 3][STRING_MAXIMO];/*Declaramos um array de n posições (nº casas é sempre o nivel + 3 exemplo nivel 1 -> 4 casas; 
    nivel 3 -> 6 casas) e com o tamanho maximo de uma string (caracteres numa cor)*/
    char palpite[nivel + 3][STRING_MAXIMO];/*Array que guardará os palpites do jogador*/

    gerarTabuleiro(nivel, tabuleiro);


    /*Teste*/
    //Impressão do tabuleiro - retirar em versão final
    printf("| ");
    for(index = 0; index != nivel + 3; index++){
        printf("%s | ", tabuleiro[index]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    /*Fim de teste*/

    
    //Declaração e inicialização de variaveis locais
    int novoPalpite;//Variavel que ira permitir ao utilizador desistir do jogo ou continuar a dar palpites (1 -> continuar || 2 -> desistir)
    int tentativas = 0;//Variavel que irá contar o numero de palpites que o jogador necessitou para ganhar
    int numeroDeBrancas = 0, numeroDePretas = 0;//Variaveis que informarão o jogador de quão perto se encontra de ganhar

    do{
        //Pedido ao utilziador do seu palpite
        printf("# Insira o seu palpite #\n");
        for(index = 0; index != nivel + 3; index++){//Para cada casa do nivel atual
            printf("# Casa %i\t", index + 1);//Sera informada a posição atual da casa a preencher
            scanf("%s", palpite[index]);//E pedido ao utilziador que escolha uma cor para a preencher
        }
        tentativas++;

        numeroDePretas = calculaPretas(nivel, tabuleiro, palpite);
        numeroDeBrancas = calculaBrancas(nivel, tabuleiro, palpite);
        printf("###########################################\n");
        printf("# Numero de peças pretas: %i               #\n", numeroDePretas);
        printf("#Numero de peças brancas: %i               #\n", numeroDeBrancas);
        printf("###########################################\n");

        if(numeroDePretas == nivel + 3){
            printf("###########################################\n");
            printf("# Necessitou de %i tentativas para ganhar  #\n", tentativas);
            printf("#                  TABULEIRO              #\n# ");
            for(index = 0; index != nivel + 3; index++)
                printf("%s # ", tabuleiro[index]);
            printf("\n###########################################\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("# Deseja introduzir um novo palpite #\n");
        printf("# 1. Novo palpite #\n");
        printf("# 2. Desistir #\n");
        scanf("%i", &novoPalpite);

        if(novoPalpite == 2){
            printf("# Desistiu do jogo #\n");
            printf("# Tabuleiro #\n ");
            printf("| ");
            for(index = 0; index != nivel + 3; index++)
                printf("%s | ", tabuleiro[index]);
            printf("\n\n");
        }

    }while(novoPalpite == 1);//Peças pretas (cor e posição correta)

    return 0;
}
```

I make one cycle controlled by indexP iterate on the guess from the player and another cycle iterating on the board it self, if the string is the same in any position execept in the same postion of both (definition of black piece) and i verify if the piece as already conteded as a white piece (i think this is the part that isn't workin but im not sure)

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Make a separate program that has just `main`, the function that you have a problem with, and just additional code needed to make it run and show the problem. Set up `main` with data that reproduces the problem. Show the actual observed output from the program and show the output you desire instead.

Comment: First count how many times each color (verde, azul, rosa, ...) appears in the answer. Then for each black peg found by `calculaPretas`, reduce the count for the corresponding color. In `calculaBrancas`, a white peg is awarded if the guessed color is not in the correct position, and the count for that color is still greater than 0. After awarding a white peg, reduce the count for the corresponding color.

Comment: The code will be easier to write if you use numbers for the colors instead of strings.

Comment: There is no need for 1 `printf()` per-line of output (that's what `'\n'` is for). You only need a single `printf()` for any continual block of text regardless of the number of lines (or `puts()` or `fputs()` if no conversions are involved - depending on end-of-line control required). Simply remove all `printf()` except the first, remove the `);` from the end of all but the last leaving the separate lines as you have them -- and you are done.

Answer (score -1):

OT: This code is unreadable with its often duplicated comments, even if one knows the language (which I do not.)

Here is your first function re-written:

```
void gerarTabuleiro(int nivel, char tabuleiro[][] ) {
    char coresNivel[] = {
        "vermelho", "verde", "azul", "amarelo", "rosa", "ciano", "castanho", "roxo"
    };

    srand(time(NULL));

    for( int i = 0; i < nivel + 3; i++ )
        strcpy( tabuleiro[ i ], coresNivel[ rand() % (nivel + 5)] );
}
```

Instead of copy/paste, strive to write crisp, concise code that achieves the objective.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand your suggestion (im "new" to c programing) but that was not my faulty function.
Do you recomend any tutorial or anything to watch to write a better code?

Comment: While this does not address the problem you are having, it is meant to show the benefit of re-examining code you've written to try to make it more obvious. "Muddy" code with "copy/paste" blocks and unnecesary comments is where problems start. The above code is now so small you may consider using it in `main()` and eliminate one function completely. As suggested by someone in the comments, using numbers instead of strings (`strcmp()`) would simplify the logic immensely. Experience comes slowly. Try to write less, but more clear and effective, code.